# I can't find an easy way to access a dGrid Store

Tags: javascript, dojo, frameworks, dgrid

I have an App from a former Programmer. This guy was using dojo, djox and dGrid.

As I only have the task to write a simple export from the dojo or dGrid I am searching for an easy way to access the dGrid's Store. As far as I understand the store holds all the information how the Grid is ordered in a particulary moment.

Search for something like
dGridStore.retrieveAll.

Another cool solution for this problem might be finding a physical json of the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can access the store you can simply do the following.

```
  var gridList= store.query();
   console.log(JSON.stringify(gridList));
```

if you can show me more code i can help you more.

Comment: thanks. its confidental sorry...where should I run this code that it works?

Comment: no problem, I don't want to see everything I just wanted to help you with how to get the store from the grid. did that help you or you need more info ??

Comment: its to big and contains thousand of files. so where is the store usally initiated?

Comment: If it was me I would do it exactly before Creating and populating the grid like the example in this JS http://jsfiddle.net/MG9jB/168/

Comment: ok I think got the right position but it hangs on .then ? why?

Comment: TypeError: gridList.then is not a function
gridList.then(function(results) {

Comment: I just edit my answer, can you try again, this is all assuming that you are Using a memory store. if you are using a memory store this should work if you are using some other store please tell me what is the store type

Comment: ok got it with 
console.log(JSON.stringify(dGridStore.query()));
just only has not the right order I specified

Comment: so was my answer okay to you ??

Comment: yes but can yiôu help getting it i nthe right order of columns and rows?

Comment: They should be coming in the right order of the layout at least